# How to display row number and order by the ID DESC which is primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns (id,gp, village, year) id as primary key.
Table name is **files_dev** columns are **id, gp, village, year**

```
id  gp  village year
1   a1  xyz     2000
2   b1  abc     2001
3   c1  def     1999
```

i want like this to display, but the id column should start with serial order 1 2 3 4. I know since it is primary key and set it to auto increment, i have seen setting row numbers will work but how to do it.

```
id  gp  village year
4   a4  def     1999
1   a1  xyz     2000
2   a2  abc     2001
3   a3  def     1999
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question! There is no match in the sample and expected data; I am seeing gp with value a2,  a3 which are not found in the original data.

Comment: I am just trying to show the sample data but what i really want is if a new row is added it will be shown last in the database but i want it to be displayed in the first row and the Id should be changed with proper numbering format if not ID will display new column name like row number